# Accessing properties in org-babel source code blocks

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

noweb expantion is a very nice tool but it generally allows one to refer to other src-code blocks:

```
#+NAME: hellomessage
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
"hello"
#+END_SRC

#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :noweb yes 
(message <<hellomessage>>)
#+END_SRC
```

works perfectly. But it is reasonable to want to do template expansion with properties. I would like something like this to work:

```
#+PROPERTY: hellomessage hello

#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :noweb yes 
(message "<<hellomessage>>")
#+END_SRC
```

or

```
* Example
  :PROPERTIES:
  :hellomessage: hello
  :END:

#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :noweb yes 
(message "<<hellomessage>>")
#+END_SRC
```

but it doesn't since noweb seems only to expand named source blocks. 
Is there any way to do this?

I have thought of using header arguments with the var keyword but that seems somewhat artificial since the property then is "specific" to src blocks. I would like to avoid this since I would also want to use the property in the normal org-mode way.

Similarly to what Ixemad suggested I tried doing this

```
* Example
  :PROPERTIES:
  :hellomessage: hello
  :END:

  #+NAME: get_property
  #+BEGIN_SRC elisp :var prop=""
    (org-entry-get nil prop t)
  #+END_SRC
  #+RESULTS: get_property

  #+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :noweb yes
    (message "<<get_property("hellomessage")>>")
  #+END_SRC

  #+RESULTS:
  : hello1
```

but the problem is that the `org-entry-get` gets evaluated where the `get_property` code block is defined, not where it is called as seen by the following example

```
* Example1
  :PROPERTIES:
  :hellomessage: hello1
  :END:

  #+NAME: get_property
  #+BEGIN_SRC elisp :var prop=""
    (org-entry-get nil prop t)
  #+END_SRC
  #+RESULTS: get_property

  #+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :noweb yes
    (message "<<get_property("hellomessage")>>")
  #+END_SRC

  #+RESULTS:
  : hello1

* Example2
  :PROPERTIES:
  :hellomessage: hello2
  :END:
  #+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :noweb yes
    (message "<<get_property("hellomessage")>>")
  #+END_SRC

  #+RESULTS:
  : hello1
```

The second result should have been `hello2`.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not entirely sure I understand the constraints/requirements you're interested in (e.g. must a solution involve noweb evaluation), but one aspect of this question is similar to a problem I wrestled with recently: block calls and their location.  The best solution I could find made use of `org-babel-current-src-block-location`.

Here are some examples; one uses Elisp only and the other uses noweb block evaluation and `org-babel-current-src-block-location`.  Both appear to solve the block-location problem, if I'm understanding it correctly.

```
  * Example
    :PROPERTIES:
    :hellomessage: hello
    :END:

    #+NAME: get_property
    #+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :var prop_name="" :results silent
    (org-with-point-at org-babel-current-src-block-location
      (org-entry-get nil prop_name t))
    #+END_SRC

    #+HEADER: :var prop_message=(org-entry-get nil "hellomessage" t)
    #+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
      (message prop_message)
    #+END_SRC

    #+RESULTS:
    : hello

    #+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :noweb yes
      (message "<<get_property("hellomessage")>>")
    #+END_SRC

    #+RESULTS:
    : hello

  * Example2
    :PROPERTIES:
    :hellomessage: hello2
    :END:


    #+HEADER: :var prop_message=(org-entry-get nil "hellomessage" t)
    #+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
      (message prop_message)
    #+END_SRC

    #+RESULTS:
    : hello2

    #+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :noweb yes
      (message "<<get_property("hellomessage")>>")
    #+END_SRC

    #+RESULTS:
    : hello2
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [Noweb reference syntax](https://orgmode.org/manual/Noweb-reference-syntax.html#Noweb-reference-syntax), you can evaluate code block before expansion.

```
* Example
  :PROPERTIES:
  :hellomessage: hello
  :END:

  #+NAME: get_property
  #+BEGIN_SRC elisp :var prop=""
    (org-entry-get nil prop t)
  #+END_SRC
  #+RESULTS: get_property

  #+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :noweb
    (message "<<get_property("hellomessage")>>")
  #+END_SRC
```

Comment: I tried and this doesn't work. First of all to make it work I need to change it `:noweb` to `:noweb yes`. But most importantly the above code gets the property in the entry where `get_property` is defined, not where it is called. I will add the clarifying example in my question.